# Pure Swift class conforming to protocol with static method - issue with upcasting

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

Given we have a Swift protocol with one `static` method:

```
protocol Creatable: class {
    static func create() -> AnyObject
}
```

and a pure Swift class which conforms to the protocol:

```
class Foo : Creatable {
    static func create() -> AnyObject {
        return Foo() as AnyObject
    }
}
```

Later on when one tries to make use of that protocol by operating on type `Creatable` e.g.:

```
var f : Creatable = Foo.self
f.create()
```

The compiler complains with the following:

```
error: type 'Foo.Type' does not conform to protocol 'Creatable'
```

The question is: is this a Swift limitation or I'm using the protocols and static/class method in the wrong way.

Objective-C equivalent would be something like:

```
Class someClass = [Foo class];
if ([someClass conformsToProtocol:@protocol(Creatable)]) {
    [(Class <Foo>)someClass create];
}
```

Comment: At first I wonder about the static function in a class.. `static` is actually for `struct`s and `class` for 'static' class functions

Comment: @OliverBorchert: in swift 1.2 we've got _real_ static, including stored properties

Comment: Oh I haven't realized yet, thanks for the hint ^_^

Answer (score 9):

A `Creatable` reference points to an *instance* of `Foo`, not to the `Foo` type itself.

To get the equivalent of the class-level protocol implementation, you need an instance of `Creatable.Type`:

```
let c: Creatable.Type = Foo.self
```

However, you’ll get an error when you then try to use it:

```
// error: accessing members of protocol type value 'Creatable.Type' is unimplemented
c.create()
```

All that said, is there a reason why you can’t just use functions to fulfill your requirement, instead of metatypes?

```
let f = Foo.create
// f is now a function, ()->AnyObject, that creates Foos
let someFoo = f()
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The reason I try to work with meta types is that I'm working on a factory of objects. Ideally I would create an new instance out of the type itself. But as I found it's not possible with the Swift's strong typing architecture. As a workaround I thought  about using the protocol with static method approach. This way I could collect meta types which conform to the protocol and create objects. Maybe I am mistaken and there's a better way of creating factory.

Comment: "Ideally I would create an new instance out of the type itself. But as I found it's not possible with the Swift's strong typing architecture.”  You mean, you have an instance, and you want to clone it?  Swift’s type system has a number of ways to do this.

Comment: I would like to achieve a standard factory with an API which accepts type as parameter and returns the object. The problem is with defining such method, the input parameter has to be generic type. I've tried to use generics, with type constraint: `create<T: Createable>(type :T)` , but it complains that the static methods is not visible.

Comment: The following code ought to work.  However, there is probably a better way of solving your problem than the way you are trying to get working, abstract factories are more useful in languages that don't have a good generic implementation and first-class functions in the first place.  `protocol Creatable { static func create() -> AnyObject }; func create<T: Creatable>(type: T.Type) -> AnyObject { return T.create() };class S: Creatable { static func create() -> AnyObject { return S() } };let s = create(S.self)`

Comment: Thanks I will give it a thought. Meanwhile your suggestion for generic function parameter: `type: T.Type` did what I expected. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

Using `.Type` is the key:

```
var f : Creatable.Type = Foo.self
```

And this no longer gives the "unimplemented" error.  See full code below:

```
protocol Creatable: class {
    static func create() -> AnyObject
}

class Foo : Creatable {
    static func create() -> AnyObject {
        return Foo() as AnyObject
    }
}

var f : Creatable.Type = Foo.self
f.create()
```

Comment: Has something changed since the similar answer above which say this is not possible?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The highest-scored one has wrong or, most likely, pretty much outdated info.